# Vue JS - how to list directory in public folder?

Tags: vuejs2

This is a snippet of my directory structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVvW.png)

I have a songs folder under "public" directory containing a bunch of mp3 files.
I want my vue app to play a random song from that file

Everything is kinda settled, except for getting the paths (of the mp3 files) dynamically

For instance, if there are the following files in my public/songs directory - song1.mp3, song2.mp3 and song3.mp3, how do i get the list in vue js - ["song1.mp3", "song2.mp3", "song3.mp3"]?

Thank you

Comment: You will need to have the web server publish the list of available songs. This is however, not vue-related in any way, I guess.